# OSSEC windows agent configuration

Tags: ossec

I am getting started with OSSEC and i want to configure windows agent. I have followed the [documentation](https://ossec-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual/agent/agent-management.html) and [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-monitor-ossec-agents-using-an-ossec-server-on-ubuntu-14-04#step-6-%E2%80%94-import-the-key-from-server-to-agent). My server is a VM ubuntu and I want to have an Windows Agent.

This is the output of active agents.

> vm:/var/ossec/etc# /var/ossec/bin/list_agents -c
> ** No agent available.
>
> vm:~/ossec-hids-3.2.0# tcpdump -i ens3 src 192.168.8.69
>
> tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
>
> listening on ens3, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
>
> 13:44:30.979244 IP 192.168.8.69.55341 > 10.0.0.4.ssh: Flags [.], ack >1445060350, win 16319, length 0

This is list of already added agents.

> Available agents:    ID: 003, Name: WindowsAgent, IP: 192.168.8.69

And here is my windows agent manager.

[image]

On the server side I have droped the firewall.

Maybe should I drop the firewall also on the client side? Also I am not so sure about server side IP address - but thats the output form ifconfig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a mistake assuming that ifconfig ip is the one I should be connecting. My server is on the VM, which I connect via SSH to given IP and this IP is the OSSEC server IP.

Here is the command to check whether the port 1514 is used.

> `tcpdump -i ens3 -nn host 192.168.8.69 and port 1514`

It shows whether you are using a specific port.

Also, I advise checking `ossec.log` in ossec-agent folder.